# Allocating a new buffer per each frame to prevent screen tearing

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, sdl

When I use the SDL library to set the pixel values in the memory and update the screen, screen tearing occurs whenever the update is too fast. I don't know much about the SDL internals, but my understanding from what I see is that:

1. The update function returns right after signalling the graphics hardware to read the pixel data from (say) `buffer1`.
2. The next frame is painted on `buffer2`, and update is called again, but this was too fast and the reading from `buffer1` still hasn't completed;
3. My program doesn't know anything about the hardware and assumes that its okay to paint again in `buffer1`, while this buffer is being sent to the monitor.
4. The screen is torn.

This isn't a big problem when the velocity of the to-be-painted object is not too fast. The screen still tears, but it is almost non-visible to the human eye, but I'd still be happy if this tearing does not occur at all. I dislike vertical sync, as it produces consistent latency per each frame.

My idea is that probably a new screen buffer can be allocated per each frame to be painted on. When the monitor wants to display something, it should read from the newest buffer.

Is this a possible way already used in practice? If I do want to test my idea, what kind of low level and cross platform library or API I may use? SDL? OpenGL?

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with buffers, everything to do with the exact time you update the screen.  Google "sdl vertical sync", you can't miss SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Probable? **NO**. Usually you'll see double (2) or triple (3) buffering used. The buffers are preallocated.

Comment: @HansPassant I know I can always do vertical syncing, I mentioned about it in the original post that I'd like to avoid the consistent latency from it.

Comment: If you change the screen contents while it's refreshing, you're going to get tearing. The only way to avoid it is to accept the latency. I would hope there's a way to utilize multiple buffers while waiting for the sync so that only the latest ready one is used, and you're not stuck waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think that updating the screen faster than the human eye can see it is productive?  if you really must have your engine 100% independent of the retrace, use a triple buffer system.  One buffer to display, and 2 buffers to update back and forth to until the screen is ready for the next buffer.  Triple is as high as you need to go as if you fill the 2nd back buffer, you can just write over the now defunct 1st back buffer instead.  No GPU lag and only 3 buffers.

[Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82318/what-problem-does-double-or-triple-buffering-solve-in-modern-games) is a nice link describing this technique along with some warnings about using it on modern GPUs...

Comment: Your link answered all of my questions!